# Detecting batch SQL statements

Tags: sql, sqlite, ms-access

Is there a general mechanism to detect batch SQL statements (i.e. consisting of multiple statements separated by semi-colons)? Our supported databases are `MS Access` and `SQLite`, but this is a general question for any database type.

Consider statement 1:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name LIKE '%fred%'; SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

This consists of two statements. Now consider statement 2:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name LIKE '%fred;%';
```

This is a single statement only. Is there a simple trick to tell the difference?

Comment: I think you would have to re-invent SQL parsing to a certain degree. What's the use case for this?

Comment: This is plain impossible without specifying the SQL dialect and having a dialect-specific parser (or at least a tokenizer). While heuristics may be available, they won't be reliable

Answer (score 0):

Count and locate the semicolons:

```
 IsBatchCommand = IIf(Len(SQL) = Len(Replace(SQL, ";", "")), False, Trim(Mid(SQL, InStr(SQL, ";") + 4)) <> "")
```

Comment: Have you programmed in C in an earlier life? ;-) -- But I think this would fail on the 2nd example (`;` in string)

Comment: @Andre: I wish I had but never got further than C#. It was air code; now checked in VBA and corrected.